# Does cross-sectional area affect the air time of a vertically thrown object?

Tags: forces, gravity, drag, aerodynamics

Factoring in air resistance, I have two objects A and B of identical mass, however have different cross-sectional areas. A has a larger cross-sectional area than B. If I throw both objects directly upwards with the same amount of force applied to each, would both objects reach their initial launch height at the same time?

I believe the answer to this would be yes as object A area would experience a greater air resistance upwards, therefore decelerate quicker and as a result not reach as high of an elevation as object B. Then, as A begins to fall, there is more air resistance than B, therefore A accelerates slower than B. The result is both of them landing at the same time.

Would someone be able to confirm if this is the case or not, and if not, explain what would occur?

Comment: Is the landing height the same as the launch height? Then I would agree.

Comment: Yes, the launch height is the landing height

Comment: Another constraint: The bodies must have a symmetrical shape on their upper and lower side. Only then will drag be the same, regardless of direction of movement. Also, all bets are off if one starts to tumble.